# How to use TableViewController Class in TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my App I want to display a TWTRTimelineViewController (TableViewController) in an UIViewController. But the Code for the TWTRTimelineViewController is only working in an **UITableViewController Class** and not in an UITableView Classe. Is there a way to solve this, for example to **display** an UITableViewController at a y-postition in an **UIViewController**? 
Thanks!

Comment: to display an `UITableViewController` or `tableview`?

Comment: Did you mean fix the uitableview inside uiviewcontroller with custom height and width right??

Comment: You can add UITableView as subview for your UIViewController. Also you should implement UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewTableDataSource protocols in your UITableView class.

Comment: UITableViewController‘s rootview is UITableView, and controller as the view's delegate to manager view's contents or event.

Comment: @aaisataev a TableViewController

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `UIViewController` than include a tableView using the storyboard and connect it with the `UIViewController` (`@IBOutlet`). Next you will set a identifier to the tableView prototype cell. Than in your UIViewController you will extend the delegates `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and implement the protocols.

[This tutorial](http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/) is pretty much detailed and will give you all the steps to achieve what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my case the Problem is that I'm using a ViewController. In that View Controller there should be a TWTRTimelineViewController. So it's a thirdparty Class. I tryed to implement that to my ViewController Class but it says that it cannot conform to protocol because it has requirements that cannot ne satisfied...

Comment: U didnt mention thhis in the question. Please update the question so people can help you with proper explanation

Comment: Sry I didn't knew that this is important

Answer (score 1):

You can not set UITableViewController custom class in UITableView,if the 3rd party class you are using is UITableViewController then you must use it in UITableViewController from storyboard